# Adding attribute values to table record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to insert user_id when product#create action.

How to insert user_id in productController??

user is just model.

here is
products_controller.rb

```
  def create

    @user = current_user
    @product = Product.new(product_params, user_id: user_id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save

        format.html { redirect_to wardrobe_items_path, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

product table

```
class AddUserIdToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :user_id, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: use Product.new(product_params, user_id: @user.id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
@product = Product.new(product_params)
@product.user_id = current_user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Do This...

```
def create

    @user = current_user
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save

        format.html { redirect_to wardrobe_items_path, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```